# How to apply styles for a Datetime Picker Text Box

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Hello in my project i have to apply styles for a textbox which will render Calender using Jquery and css. Am using ASP.Net MVC3 Razor

**Here is my Text Box Code**

```
<div class="col-lg-10" >@Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateOfBirth, new { @class = "form-control"  })
```

**My Template Text box which is binded with a script**

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="dp1" data-date-format="mm/dd/yy" value="02/16/12"></div>
```

My question is how to apply the below styles for the above text box

> **type="text" id="dp1" data-date-format="mm/dd/yy" value="02/16/12"**

**Script Code**

```
/*==DATE PICKER==*/
             $('#dp1').datepicker({
                 format: 'mm-dd-yyyy'
             });
             $('#dp2').datepicker();
             $('#dpYears').datepicker();
             $('#dpMonths').datepicker();
         });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply create your own editor template for this and reuse wherever you are required.

```
 @Html.EditorFor(m => m.DateOfBirth, "DatePicker")
```

Then `Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/DatePicker.cshtml` file write the below

```
@model DateTime?
@{
    String modelValue = "";


    if (Model.HasValue)
    {
        if (Model.Value != DateTime.MinValue)
        {
            modelValue = Model.Value.ToShortDateString();
        }
    }
}

    @Html.TextBox("", modelValue, new { @class = 'my-date-picker'})
```

Then your CSS

```
.my-date-picker
{ 
  /* your styles */
}
```

Javascript in a main page or _layout(if it is used across more pages)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.my-date-picker').datepicker();

});
```

Comment: hello Where i have to create Editor Template ,inside Views or Shared? and here my problem is i have to use id inside this new {}?

Answer (score 0):

You can't set class for the `EditorFor`

Change

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateOfBirth, new { @class = "form-control"  })
```

To

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DateOfBirth, new { @class = "form-control"  })
```

Other way to add class can be using jquery in `document.ready` handler

```
$('#dp1').addClass('form-control');
```

Comment: ,hello i have set the class ,thats working , i want to know how to set the remaining elements"type="text" id="dp1" data-date-format="mm/dd/yy" value="02/16/12""

Comment: Didnt get u, what u r asking?. u can update ur question